# Filter a observable collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an animal class. A `herbivore` class which inherits from animal and an `elephant` class which inherits from `herbivore`. I also have a `carnivore` class which inherits from `animal` and a `tiger` class which inherits from `carnivore`. I Have a observable collection called zoo with tigers and elephants. I Want to select the Herbivores in the zoo collection. I Then want to add the herbivores to a new observable collection called herb.

```
var herbivores = from Animal in zoo
                 where Animal == Animal.OfType<Herbivore>()
                 select Animal;

foreach (var item in herbivores)
{
    herb.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question here.

Comment: sorry its giving errors where  have i gone wrong

Comment: You need to explain what your errors are, and where they are.  Saying nothing more than "it is giving errors" is not helpful.  You need to describe the problems you have with your attempted solution *in detail*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `OfType` like that; it's an extension method on an enumerable collection, not on the class `animal`. Do this instead:

```
var herbivores = zoo.OfType<Herbivore>();
```

Alternatively you could achieve the same effect with

```
var herbivores = zoo.Where(a => a is Herbivore);
```

but there really is no point in doing this the funky way.

Comment: Plus, there is no reason for the `for`-loop afterwards. I don't know where `herb` is coming from, but you can pass the `herbivores` into the constructor, or use `AddRange` if you want to keep your existing data.

Comment: The distinction between OfType and Where..is is that in the first case herbivores will be an `IEnumerable<Herbifore>` whereas the second will be `IEnumerable<animal>`. You can also express the second as `from a in zoo where a is Herbivore select a` if you prefer the LINQ syntax (and want the type to remain animal)